# Marionette - Region Manager required understanding

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am creating a app using, Marionettejs. It woks fine. but I confused with 'Layout' and 'Region Manager'. without using the Region Manager My view works fine. But how can i use the region Manager?

In my region I have 2 containers namely 'navi' and 'content' - when i render the navi i don't require the content. - is the time to play with region manager here?

if so ho can i do that? I came across with doc, But still I am not clear with this all.

any one detail me please?

here is my working example, please update the fiddle to see the result.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hL2fqyyj/4/)

script:

```
var MenuView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:_.template($('#menuTemp').html()),
    render:function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});


//how can i use this?

var rm = new Marionette.RegionManager();
rm.addRegion("foo", "#bar");

//

container = new Backbone.Marionette.Region({
  el: "#container"
});

MyLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#my-layout",

  regions: {
    menu: "#menu",
    content: "#content"
  }
});

// Show the "layout" in the "container" region
layout = new MyLayout();
container.show(layout);
layout.removeRegion("content");

layout.menu.show(new MenuView().render()); //not working
```

Comment: If you use Layout u dont need implement Region manager manually as LayoutView is a combination of view and Regions

Comment: Ok, Agree. then how to I remove the 'content' while only i use the 'menu' - i am looking for remove and add the container whenever i need from layout!

Comment: btw you have an error in `layout.menu.show(new MenuView().render());` you dont need call `render` method `show` make it auto

Comment: could you please describe the task in details, cant catch you idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout will hold regions - you don't need to worry about region manager. So you could define a layout like this:

```
 class Show.Layout extends App.Views.Layout
  template: "surveys/show/show_layout"

  regions: 
    questionRegion: "#question-region"
    newRegion: "#new-region"
    panelRegion: "#panel-region"
    bannerRegion: "#banner-region"
```

And you'd initialize/show it in your controller:

```
class Show.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: (options) ->
      { survey, id } = options
      survey or= App.request "survey:entity", id

      App.execute "when:fetched", survey, =>
        @layout = @getLayoutView()

        @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @panelRegion survey
          @questionRegion survey
          @bannerRegion survey

        @show @layout

    questionRegion: (survey) ->
      App.request "show:survey:questions", survey, @layout.questionRegion

    panelRegion: (survey) ->
      panelView = @getPanelView survey

      @show panelView, region: @layout.panelRegion

    bannerRegion: (survey) ->
      bannerView = @getBannerView survey    

      @show bannerView, region: @layout.bannerRegion

    getLayoutView: ->
      new Show.Layout

    getBannerView: (survey) ->
      new Show.Banner
        model: survey

    getPanelView: (survey) ->
      new Show.Panel
        model: survey

    getQuestionView: (questions, survey) ->
      new Show.Questions
        collection: questions
        model: survey
```

Basically you listen to the show method and when the layout is shown you show each of the regions.

I do override the show method in my controllers:

```
  class Controllers.Application extends Marionette.Controller

    constructor: (options = {}) ->
      @region = options.region or App.request "default:region"
      super options
      @_instance_id = _.uniqueId("controller")
      App.execute "register:instance", @, @_instance_id

    close: ->
      App.execute "unregister:instance", @, @_instance_id
      super

    show: (view, options = {}) ->
      _.defaults options,
        loading: false
        region: @region
      view = if view.getMainView then view.getMainView() else view
      throw new Error("getMainView() did not return a view instance or #{view?.constructor?.name} is not a view instance") if not view

      @setMainView view
      @_manageView view, options

    getMainView: ->
      @_mainView

    setMainView: (view) ->
      return if @_mainView
      @_mainView = view
      @listenTo view, "close", @close

    _manageView: (view, options) ->
      if options.loading
        App.execute "show:loading", view, options
      else
        options.region.show view

    mergeDefaultsInto: (obj) ->
      obj = if _.isObject(obj) then obj else {}
      _.defaults obj, @_getDefaults()

    _getDefaults: ->
      _.clone _.result(@, "defaults")
```

This is all patterned off of what I learned from backbonerails.com. He does a far better job explaining it than me :).

Comment: Perhaps answering in coffescript when the question is pure javascript won't help the user :)

Comment: Haha maybe but javascript is so blah :)

Comment: @CharlieBrown can you update the same with instead of coffescript to JavaScript please? still i got the answer i am not able to implement..!